# How can I speed up this IronPython code that generates a string of arbitrary size

Tags: c#, python, string, performance, ironpython

I have a python script that runs within a C# application (the source of which I cannot control), and I want this script to generate a file of an arbitrary size. The data in this file does not matter. I wrote the following code:

```
def generateFile(filename, size):
    file = open(filename, 'wb')
    file.write(''.join('0' for _ in range(size)))
    file.close()
```

IronPython integration in this C# application is very slow overall, but mostly acceptable. This piece of code however is too slow. It takes around 20 seconds to generate a 1KB file, and I need to generate files of around 1M or more.

After some investigation it seems that the slowness comes mainly from generating the string that is used to write to the file.

Is there another method of achieving the same task, but in faster, acceptable time?

Comment: Try `file.write('0' * size)`

Comment: @thefourtheye That works perfectly.... o_o Please put it as an answer. I guess I should try the other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
file.write('0'.zfill(size))
```

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but there are also other valid answers like what @thefourtheye wrote in the comments in the question

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how it can possibly be that slow;

Regardless, this may help; instead of making a megabyte string all at once, I generate 32K and reuse it as many times as are needed. You can play with the chunk size to see what works best.

On my machine, this writes a 100MB file in 0.81 seconds.

```
CHUNK_SIZE = 32768       # 32k (arbitrary choice)

def generateFile(filename, bytes):
    n, r = divmod(bytes, CHUNK_SIZE)
    chunk = "0" * CHUNK_SIZE
    with open(filename, 'w') as outf:
        for _ in range(n):
            outf.write(chunk)
        outf.write(chunk[:r])
```

Comment: This is probably the ideal approach for very large files (several hundred MBs or more). For my needs however, it's slightly complex.